# Plotting bode plot of the transfer function

Tags: transfer-function, bode-plot

[image]

two poles p1=1 and p2=25
two zeros are z1=100 and z2=origin 
and the DC gain is 20log10(10)=20dB
I know that that the Dc gain Is 20dB which is a straight line with slope of 0 , 
The zeroes have 20dB slope, but I don’t know how to find amplitude of poles ( vertical positions) and and at what vertical position does the graph start ?

Comment: It is very easy plotting bode plot on Matlab. In my humble opinion, it can help you, maybe.

Comment: I cannot use MATLAB in this course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, cancel out the pole and zero:

\$H(s) = 250s/(s+25)\$

Next, determine the pole location:

\$H(s) = 10s/(1+s/25)\$

The break frequency is 25 rad/s.

Since there is a zero at origin, the slope until 25 rad/s is +20 dB and the slope after 25 rad/s is 0 dB.

We can start the graph at 1/10th of the lowest break frequency: 2.5 rad/s but that's quite an odd number.  Let's select 1 rad/s instead.

The gain at 1 rad/s is:

\$H(1) = 10*1/(1)\ = 10 = 20 \textbf{dB}\$

This does not directly tell us the gain at and beyond the 25 rad/s break frequency.  We know that the gain difference between the gains at the break frequency and at 1/10th of the break frequency is 20 **dB**.

Thus, let's determine the gain at 2.5 rad/s:

\$H(2.5) = 10*2.5/(1)\ = 25 = 28 \textbf{dB}\$

Gain at 1/10th of the break frequency is 28 **dB**.  One can draw vertical line from 20 **dB** at 1 rad/s through 28 **dB** at 2.5 rad/s to 48 **dB** at 25 rad/s.  At 25 rad/s, the gain slope becomes zero and hence one can draw a horizontal line at 48 **dB** to ~1,000 rad/s.

Also, notice that the DC gain is 0, which is a number that cannot be represented on a logarithmic scale.

\$H(0) = 10*0/(1)\ = 0\$

MatLab:

[image]

Comment: can you share the MATLAB command ?

Comment: s = tf('s'); H = 250*s*(s+100)/(s+100)/(s+25); bode(H)